# InvalidSessionDescriptionError: Invalid description, no ice-ufrag attribute

Tags: webrtc, asterisk, sip

I'm trying to get asterisk 11.20.0 running with WebRTC (sip.js 0.72 which I believe is a fork of jssip), but I'm seeing the following (and the called party rings, but when the phone is answered the call gets hung up).

**This is my setup:**

[image: My setup]

What I see:

**In the CLI:**

`[2015-11-24 01:01:53] NOTICE[43619][C-00000002]: res_rtp_asterisk.c:4441 ast_rtp_read: Unknown RTP codec 95 received from '(null)'`

**In Firefox:**

`InvalidSessionDescriptionError: Invalid description, no ice-ufrag attribute`

Attachments:

- [SIP Dialogue](http://pastebin.com/jsE6UrFk) (Asterisk CLI)
- [Webphone Log](http://pastebin.com/v5Ht7cJw)
- [Config Files](http://pastebin.com/PA0jvBgD) (httpd.conf, sip.conf, rtp.conf)
- [Asterisk Compiled with Libuuid & Friends](http://pastebin.com/C077p6NN)

**What I've tried so far:**

- Changed webRTC implementations (tried chrome and firefox both with SIPML and SIP.JS)
- Set the STUN server to null on the client side (stunServers: ['stun:null'])
- Configured properly (I hope) my sip.conf and rtp.conf and httpd.conf
- Made sure I have libuuid, uuid and their -devel companions and after i've recompiled asterisk.

**What I've read:**

- http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?p=201702
- https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+WebRTC+Support
- https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/WebRTC+tutorial+using+SIPML5
- http://jssip.net/documentation/misc/interoperability/asterisk/
- http://sipjs.com/guides/server-configuration/asterisk/
- https://kunjans.wordpress.com/2015/01/09/web-sip-client-sipml5-with-asterisk-13-on-centos-6-6/
- http://forums.digium.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=89798

Please, if you can, give me a hand. I'm about to smash my box with a sledge hammer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faced same issue and followed instruction in http://forums.digium.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=90167 realise that:

> This issue is caused because you asterisk don't have ICE support, you can solve that by installing the uuid/libuuid and uuid-devel/libuuid-devel packages on your system. Then recompile asterisk(be sure to rerun the configure script before the make command).

I did recompile my Astersik 11.16.0 with patch for ECDH support and fallback to prime256v1 https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/ASTERISK-25265 and looks like lost uuid support at that time. Reverting back to non-patched version (with uuid support, use to be compiled before) resolved my issue with "no ice-ufrag attribute" error in Firefox console and calls are going well now from WebRTC client SIPML5 based to asterisk, but not in opposit direction

Comment: Yeah, I missed the ./configure bit again. I installed all the libuuid(devel) and uuid(devel) . Also, Centos kinda blows for package requirements, I had to move to fedora server and it all went wonderfully.